# MTAudioProcessingTap EXC_BAD_ACCESS , doesnt always fire the finalize callback. how to Release it?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

Im trying to implement **MTAudioProcessingTap** and it works great. The problem is when Im done using the Tap and I reinstaniate my class and create a new Tap.

How Im supposely releasing the tap
1- I retain the tap as a property when created, hoping I can access it and release it later
2- In **deinit()** method of the class, I set the audiomix to nil and try to do a self.tap?.release()

The thing is.. sometimes it works and calls the FINALIZE callback and everything is great, and sometimes it doesn't and just crashes at the **tapProcess** Callback line:

```
let selfMediaInput = Unmanaged<VideoMediaInput>.fromOpaque(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap)).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Here's the full code: https://gist.github.com/omarojo/03d08165a1a7962cb30c17ec01f809a3

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation;
import MediaToolbox

protocol VideoMediaInputDelegate: class {
    func videoFrameRefresh(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) //could be audio or video
}

class VideoMediaInput: NSObject {
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.GenerateMetal.VideoMediaInput")

    var videoURL: URL!

    weak var delegate: VideoMediaInputDelegate?

    private var playerItemObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
    var displayLink: CADisplayLink!
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerItem: AVPlayerItem!
    let videoOutput = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: [String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)])
    var audioProcessingFormat:  AudioStreamBasicDescription?//UnsafePointer<AudioStreamBasicDescription>?
    var tap: Unmanaged<MTAudioProcessingTap>?

    override init(){

    }

    convenience init(url: URL){
        self.init()
        self.videoURL = url

        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)

        playerItemObserver = playerItem.observe(\.status) { [weak self] item, _ in
            guard item.status == .readyToPlay else { return }
            self?.playerItemObserver = nil
            self?.player.play()
        }

        setupProcessingTap()


        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        player.currentItem!.add(videoOutput)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: nil) {[weak self] notification in

            if let weakSelf = self {
                /*
                 Setting actionAtItemEnd to None prevents the movie from getting paused at item end. A very simplistic, and not gapless, looped playback.
                 */
                weakSelf.player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
                weakSelf.player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                weakSelf.player.play()
            }

        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)),
            name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil)

    }

    func stopAllProcesses(){
        self.queue.sync {
            self.player.pause()
            self.player.isMuted = true
            self.player.currentItem?.audioMix = nil
            self.playerItem.audioMix = nil
            self.playerItem = nil
            self.tap?.release()
        }
    }


    deinit{
        print(">> VideoInput deinited !!!! ")
        if let link = self.displayLink {
            link.invalidate()
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

        stopAllProcesses()

    }
    public func playVideo(){
        if (player.currentItem != nil) {
            print("Starting playback!")
            player.play()
        }
    }
    public func pauseVideo(){
        if (player.currentItem != nil) {
            print("Pausing playback!")
            player.pause()
        }
    }

    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        playVideo()
    }




    //MARK: GET AUDIO BUFFERS
    func setupProcessingTap(){

        var callbacks = MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks(
            version: kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0,
            clientInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()),
            init: tapInit,
            finalize: tapFinalize,
            prepare: tapPrepare,
            unprepare: tapUnprepare,
            process: tapProcess)

        var tap: Unmanaged<MTAudioProcessingTap>?
        let err = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks, kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap)
        self.tap = tap


        print("err: \(err)\n")
        if err == noErr {
        }

        print("tracks? \(playerItem.asset.tracks)\n")

        let audioTrack = playerItem.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first!
        let inputParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: audioTrack)
        inputParams.audioTapProcessor = tap?.takeRetainedValue()//tap?.takeUnretainedValue()
//        tap?.release()

        // print("inputParms: \(inputParams), \(inputParams.audioTapProcessor)\n")
        let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        audioMix.inputParameters = [inputParams]

        playerItem.audioMix = audioMix
    }

    //MARK: TAP CALLBACKS

    let tapInit: MTAudioProcessingTapInitCallback = {
        (tap, clientInfo, tapStorageOut) in
        tapStorageOut.pointee = clientInfo

        print("init \(tap, clientInfo, tapStorageOut)\n")

    }

    let tapFinalize: MTAudioProcessingTapFinalizeCallback = {
        (tap) in
        print("finalize \(tap)\n")
    }

    let tapPrepare: MTAudioProcessingTapPrepareCallback = {
        (tap, itemCount, basicDescription) in
        print("prepare: \(tap, itemCount, basicDescription)\n")
        let selfMediaInput = Unmanaged<VideoMediaInput>.fromOpaque(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap)).takeUnretainedValue()
        selfMediaInput.audioProcessingFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription(mSampleRate: basicDescription.pointee.mSampleRate,
                                                                           mFormatID: basicDescription.pointee.mFormatID, mFormatFlags: basicDescription.pointee.mFormatFlags, mBytesPerPacket: basicDescription.pointee.mBytesPerPacket, mFramesPerPacket: basicDescription.pointee.mFramesPerPacket, mBytesPerFrame: basicDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame, mChannelsPerFrame: basicDescription.pointee.mChannelsPerFrame, mBitsPerChannel: basicDescription.pointee.mBitsPerChannel, mReserved: basicDescription.pointee.mReserved)
    }

    let tapUnprepare: MTAudioProcessingTapUnprepareCallback = {
        (tap) in
        print("unprepare \(tap)\n")
    }

    let tapProcess: MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback = {
        (tap, numberFrames, flags, bufferListInOut, numberFramesOut, flagsOut) in
        print("callback \(bufferListInOut)\n")

        let selfMediaInput = Unmanaged<VideoMediaInput>.fromOpaque(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap)).takeUnretainedValue()

        let status = MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut, flagsOut, nil, numberFramesOut)
        //print("get audio: \(status)\n")
        if status != noErr {
            print("Error TAPGetSourceAudio :\(String(describing: status.description))")
            return
        }

        selfMediaInput.processAudioData(audioData: bufferListInOut, framesNumber: UInt32(numberFrames))
    }
    func processAudioData(audioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>, framesNumber: UInt32) {
        var sbuf: CMSampleBuffer?
        var status : OSStatus?
        var format: CMFormatDescription?

        //FORMAT
//        var audioFormat = self.audioProcessingFormat//self.audioProcessingFormat?.pointee
        guard var audioFormat = self.audioProcessingFormat else {
            return
        }
        status = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, asbd: &audioFormat, layoutSize: 0, layout: nil, magicCookieSize: 0, magicCookie: nil, extensions: nil, formatDescriptionOut: &format)
        if status != noErr {
            print("Error CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreater :\(String(describing: status?.description))")
            return
        }


        print(">> Audio Buffer mSampleRate:\(Int32(audioFormat.mSampleRate))")
        var timing = CMSampleTimingInfo(duration: CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(audioFormat.mSampleRate)), presentationTimeStamp: self.player.currentTime(), decodeTimeStamp: CMTime.invalid)


        status = CMSampleBufferCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                      dataBuffer: nil,
                                      dataReady: Bool(truncating: 0),
                                      makeDataReadyCallback: nil,
                                      refcon: nil,
                                      formatDescription: format,
                                      sampleCount: CMItemCount(framesNumber),
                                      sampleTimingEntryCount: 1,
                                      sampleTimingArray: &timing,
                                      sampleSizeEntryCount: 0, sampleSizeArray: nil,
                                      sampleBufferOut: &sbuf);
        if status != noErr {
            print("Error CMSampleBufferCreate :\(String(describing: status?.description))")
            return
        }
        status =   CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList(sbuf!,
                                                                  blockBufferAllocator: kCFAllocatorDefault ,
                                                                  blockBufferMemoryAllocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                  flags: 0,
                                                                  bufferList: audioData)
        if status != noErr {
            print("Error cCMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList :\(String(describing: status?.description))")
            return
        }

        let currentSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sbuf!);
        print(" audio buffer at time: \(currentSampleTime)")
        self.delegate?.videoFrameRefresh(sampleBuffer: sbuf!)

    }


}
```

How I use my class

```
self.inputVideoMedia = nil
self.inputVideoMedia = VideoMediaInput(url: videoURL)
self.inputVideoMedia!.delegate = self
```

the second time I do that.. it crashes (but not always). The times it doesnt crash I can see printed in the console the FINALIZE print.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `VideoMediaInput` is deallocated *before* the tap is deallocated (which can happen as there seems to be no way to synchronously stop a tap), then the tap callback can choke on a reference to your deallocated class.

You can fix this by passing (a wrapped, I guess) weak reference to your class. You can do it like this:

First delete your `tap` instance variable, and any references to it - it's not needed. Then make these changes:

```
class VideoMediaInput: NSObject {

    class TapCookie {
        weak var input: VideoMediaInput?

        deinit {
            print("TapCookie deinit")
        }
    }
...

    func setupProcessingTap(){
        let cookie = TapCookie()
        cookie.input = self

        var callbacks = MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks(
            version: kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0,
            clientInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(cookie).toOpaque()),
            init: tapInit,
            finalize: tapFinalize,
            prepare: tapPrepare,
            unprepare: tapUnprepare,
            process: tapProcess)
...


    let tapFinalize: MTAudioProcessingTapFinalizeCallback = {
        (tap) in
        print("finalize \(tap)\n")

       // release cookie
        Unmanaged<TapCookie>.fromOpaque(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap)).release()
    }


    let tapPrepare: MTAudioProcessingTapPrepareCallback = {
        (tap, itemCount, basicDescription) in
        print("prepare: \(tap, itemCount, basicDescription)\n")
        let cookie = Unmanaged<TapCookie>.fromOpaque(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap)).takeUnretainedValue()
        let selfMediaInput = cookie.input!
...

    let tapProcess: MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback = {
        (tap, numberFrames, flags, bufferListInOut, numberFramesOut, flagsOut) in
        print("callback \(bufferListInOut)\n")

        let cookie = Unmanaged<TapCookie>.fromOpaque(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap)).takeUnretainedValue()

        guard let selfMediaInput = cookie.input else {
            print("Tap callback: VideoMediaInput was deallocated!")
            return
        }
...
```

I'm not sure if the cookie class is necessary, it exists only to wrap the `weak` reference. Cutting edge Swift experts may know how to mash the weakness through all the teenage mutant ninja raw pointers, but I don't.

Comment: can you explain a bit what you mean by - passing a weak refence to the class - ?

Comment: your comment came in while I was explaining that!

Comment: OH MY GOD, that worked, not a single crash. I honestly dont really know whats going on there. But it works, it;s deallocating both the class and the cookie. and calling the unprepare, finalize. That GUARD prevents the crash I guess.

Comment: That's right - if you can't stop your class deallocating first, at least you can detect it.

Comment: This answer seems to assume that the code inside a process callback is safe to run after deallocation of the object using that callback.

Comment: The tap doesn't seem to be deallocated until its various process, unprepare and finalize callbacks have returned, so I don't think the answer needs to assume that.

Answer (score 4):

The audio context runs in its own real-time thread.  So audio processes don't stop synchronously with a stop or cancel function call, but some unknown time later (on the order of the duration of some number of audio samples in some internal audio buffers), after the real-time thread drains.

Thus, audio buffers, objects, and callbacks should not be released (or reallocated) until some (unknown, but less than a couple seconds) time after stopping any real-time audio stream.

Depending on deallocation object messages or instance variable states (including weak references) betweens real-time threads is reported to be currently unsafe in Swift (see WWDC 2018 session on audio).  Thus, I recommend using semaphores (outside of a real-time context, such as audio), or posix memory barriers (inside a bridged call to a C function).  (...until some future version of Swift figures out a real-time concurrency mechanism.)  (...especially on iOS or Apple Silicon (M1) devices which can re-order memory writes).

Comment: I didn't make the connection that Swift's lack of a threading model would affect weak references! Makes sense. So a weak reference would work in objective-c? I guess that doesn't matter, as taps shouldn't be written in swift or objc. Sigh, all I've done here is spread some more `MTAudioProcessingTap` misinformation. I should prefix my answer with a warning (something like use c & a memory barrier if your "this" can go out of scope).